# Checking whether the list is ordered according to the function

Tags: haskell

How can I check whether the list is ordered according to the function?

```
> ordered (<) [1,2,3,4,5]
True
> ordered (<) [5,4,3,2,1]
False
> ordered (>) [5,4,3,2,1]
True
```

I tried to write something like this, but it doesn't work - what's wrong in this code?

```
ordered :: (Ord a) => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [Integer] -> Bool
ordered f [] = True
ordered f [a] = True
ordered f (x1:x2:xs) =
    if ((f) x1 x2)
        then ordered f [x2]++xs
        else False
```

Comment: Not the problem, but a much better idea to do `(x2:xs)` instead of `[x2]++xs`

Comment: Better even would be `ordered f (x:xx@(y:_))` and then use `xx` instead of `y:xs`, but this is a minor optimization - always keep Knuth in mind: correctness before optimization

Comment: `f` is not (syntactically) an infix operator, so it should not be in parentheses.

Comment: @chepner it doesn't have to be, but it can.

Comment: `if a then b else False` is the same as `a && b`;  your code (when corrected) is then equivalent to `foldr (\ xs r -> case xs of (a:b:_) -> f a b && r ; _ -> True) True (tails xs)`. `tails` are from `Data.List`; or `(iterate (drop 1) xs)` can be used _here_ as well, instead.

Comment: @WillNess By "syntactically", I mean that the string `f` itself is not an infix operator. Even if `f` is bound to `(*)`, the correct syntax is still `f x1 x2`, not `(f) x1 x2`.

Comment: @chepner apologies for not writing out the full sentence. "it doesn't have to be in parentheses, but it can be" is what I meant. `(f)` is the same as `f` in every respect. `(f) x1 x2` is working, so can't be considered incorrect, only superfluous. I think. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With list comprehensions, it can be

```
ordered f xs = null [() | (a,b) <- zip xs (drop 1 xs), not (f a b)]
```

This can of course be coded with `any`, `and`, etc., if you're familiar with them. With list comprehensions you can just wing it, while you're still learning.

Your code is also good, it just misses some parentheses. It should be

```
       then ordered f ( [x2]++xs )
```

Incidentally, just saying

> doesn't work - what's wrong in this code?

is not enough. Surely you've tried to load this code, and have received an error message, talking something about "type mismatch", even showing you the expression in question,

```
    In the expression: ordered f [x2] ++ xs
    In the expression:
      if ((f) x1 x2) then ordered f [x2] ++ xs else False
    In an equation for `ordered':
        ordered f (x1 : x2 : xs)
          = if ((f) x1 x2) then ordered f [x2] ++ xs else False
```

which could have provided a clue. In Haskell, function application (denoted by just juxtaposition, i.e. white space) is of *highest* precedence, so your code was interpreted as `(ordered f [x2]) ++ (xs)`.

Answer (score 6):

The errors you get are twofold - first error

> ```
> $ > ghci tmp.hs
> GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tmp.hs, interpreted )
>
> tmp.hs:8:14:
>     Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer]’ with actual type ‘Bool’
>     In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘ordered f [x2]’
>     In the expression: ordered f [x2] ++ xs
>
> tmp.hs:8:14:
>     Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
>     In the expression: ordered f [x2] ++ xs
>     In the expression:
>       if ((f) x1 x2) then ordered f [x2] ++ xs else False
>     In an equation for ‘ordered’:
>         ordered f (x1 : x2 : xs)
>           = if ((f) x1 x2) then ordered f [x2] ++ xs else False
> Failed, modules loaded: none.
> ```

says essentially that you try to apply the `(++)` operator to two different lists - because `ordered f [x2] :: [Bool]` and `xs :: [Integer]`

to fix it - you simply need to add braces `ordered f ([x2] ++ xs)`

compiling this you get another error

> ```
> $ >  ghci tmp.hs
> GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tmp.hs, interpreted )
>
> tmp.hs:7:13:
>     Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Integer’
>       ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for
>             ordered :: Ord a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [Integer] -> Bool
>           at tmp.hs:3:12
>     Relevant bindings include
>       f :: a -> a -> Bool (bound at tmp.hs:6:9)
>       ordered :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [Integer] -> Bool
>         (bound at tmp.hs:4:1)
>     In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘x1’
>     In the expression: ((f) x1 x2)
> Failed, modules loaded: none.
> ```

which says that ghc cannot match any `Ord a` with the concrete type `Integer`.

The fix is to change the type signature - to the following

```
ordered :: Ord a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

---

On a side note - the algorithm can be simplified using the functions

- `and`
- `zipWith`
- `tail`

> `ordered f xs = and $ zipWith f xs (tail xs)`

Comment: you can avoid tail using pattern synonyms: `xs@(_:xs')` and use `zipWith f xs xs'`.

Comment: @Bakuriu except that it makes it fail on empty lists.

Answer (score 2):

another alternative

```
ordered f a = and $ zipWith f a (tail a)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that does not make use of builtin functions (yes it is reinventing the wheel) but provides some insight into how to tackle such problems is the following:

```
ordered :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
ordered f = ordered'
    where ordered' (x:xs@(x2:_)) = f x x2 && ordered' xs
          ordered' [_] = True
          ordered' [] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally write it like this:

```
ordered f xs = foldr go (`seq` True) xs Nothing
  where
    go x r Nothing = r (Just x)
    go x r (Just prev) = f prev x && r (Just x)
```

But some might consider that odd.

Comment: isn't the `seq` superfluous here, though, and simple `const` is enough?

Comment: @WillNess, it's definitely on the defensive side. I've been bitten in the past when a computation wasn't strict in the final value of an accumulating parameter. All was well in simple situations but went sideways when the function was used in a sufficiently complicated context.

Comment: @WillNess, to clarify: I'm not concerned about allocating a huge thunk; I'm concerned about GHC's ability to eliminate the `Just` constructor allocation, and (when the `foldr` fuses with something) to unbox numeric elements.

Comment: thanks. so, would `null[()|(a:b:_)<-tails xs, not(f a b)]` be better or worse, in that respect? or the hand-written loops (as recursive functions)? If the latter, then maybe the answer should always be "roll your own"? hmm.